# UIPanRecognizer doesn't work. My view never redrawn

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've made a UIPanRecognizer like this.

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {
        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self];
        self.origin = CGPointMake(
        self.origin.x+translation.x,self.origin.y+translation.y);
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
}
```

}

But my view never gets redrawn, that means... my drawRect wont be called again. Anybody ever tried this?

In my viewController I have this

```
UIGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.graphView action:@selector(pan:)];
[self.graphView addGestureRecognizer:pan]; 
[self updateUI];
```

My updateUI is

```
- (void)updateUI { [self.graphView setNeedsDisplay]; }
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this code should trigger a redraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your `updateUI` method when you attach the gesture recognizer to the view. You  should be doing it in your callback method `pan:`.

Also, you are leaking memory. After allocating and adding the `UIGestureRecognizer` to the view you should `release` it.

Comment: But my updateUI is in my viewcontroller and my pan: is in my graphView.

I have already released it, I just haven't posted that part of the code :)

Comment: Oh thank you, I got it to redraw now by putting [self setNeedsDisplay] in my pan:

Comment: Consider accepting the answer once the system lets you do it.